# Section for tutorials and guides

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tag-wiki, best-practices, tutorials

Many of the important things I have learned about programming best practices and security, have come from questions like this: [Guide to Website Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-website-authentication-beta). **Can we have a way to aggregate all of these tutorials/guides into an easy-to-find place that the community can edit through wiki?** There are a lot of complaints about poor programming practices. This would be a great way to help curb that and stay current with best practices as they evolve.

Answer (score 6):

Stack Overflow does its best to be an aggregate of all programming questions that the "community can edit through wiki."

What you are asking for is an **aggregate of the aggregate**; the important things; just the "good stuff." But what is important to *you* would almost certainly be missing what was important to *me*. That's why we have all this voting, and tags, and all that other search stuff... to help you cull through the piles of text to find "the good stuff" of interest to *you*.

If you are *truly* looking for a community consensus, look to the Questions `votes` or `hot` tabs. That's what the community has deemed "most interesting" *en masse*. I'm sure that's *not* really what you are looking for. So....

What you *really* want is a way to mark special pages that *you* find interesting. How about Stack Overflow favorites [alt text http://sstatic.net/mso/img/vote-favorite-off.png](http://sstatic.net/mso/img/vote-favorite-off.png), browser bookmarks, social bookmarking (Delicious, StumbleUpon), etc? Unfortunately, nobody can do that for you.

If you feel that your best-of collection is of general interest to a particular group of users, publish it in a blog or add it to one of those online social bookmarking sites. **I don't see any realistic way for Stack Overflow to bless some group of post as "the official aggregate."**

Answer (score 0):

All questions and answers are community editable if you have enough rep. Enough is 2000 for "owned" content and 100 for Community Wiki content.

As for finding them, if you want to know about topic Foo, why don't you search for "Foo"? Consider using "[foo]" because tag searches are often more precise. Well liked "guide" questions almost always have a great many votes, so they come to the top if you sort that way.

Comment: The point is making it easy to find, the wiki part is secondary. The problem with search alone, is the person often doesn't know what they are searching for. Hence a person that has only heard of MD5 hashing a password, just searches for the easiest way to implement that. The only way they would even know about salting, different encryption scemes, etc. would be by accident.